# Drag and drop to dynamically add "drop" position - cdkDropListGroup

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I need to add the number to users which I get from API.
I use cdkDropListGroup, and I get structure, but I have the following problem:

-When I drag&drop number to any of user, i get this number for all user...I need only for single user

-How to collect a given number, to store to JSON for any user in his object in json

-from list with given number I need to copy number to user,  not move, because users can have same numbers.

-we can only take number from number list and drag to user, not between users or from user to number list

-delete number from user

Here is my demo 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4ftm7-y861mb

EDIT: 
I try to add an index to  `selectedNumbers[i]` but then i get error in console

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined